# HTTP Error 405 in a user registration form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have to connect a user registration by post method in php for a subject and the teacher gave us the php code to do it but it doesn't work. Iḿ using Linux.

Here is the form, `registro.html`:

```
 <form action="registro.php" method="POST">
                <h1>Registro</h1>
                <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></div>
                <label for="name">Apellido Paterno</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Apellido Paterno"></div>
                <label for="name">Apellido Materno</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Apellido Materno"></div>
                <label for="name">Edad</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Edad"></div>
                <label for="name">Numero de telefono</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Ej.33 1234 5678"></div>
                <label for="name">Codigo Postal</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Ej. 12344"></div>
                <label for="name">Correo electronico</label>
                <div><input type="text" name="correo" id="" placeholder="Ej. hola@gmail.com"</div>
                <label for="name">Contraseña</label>
                <div><input type="password" name="contrasena" id="" placeholder="*********"></div>
                <button>REGISTRAR</button>
            </form>
```

But I get Error 405 after submitting it.

Comment: If you get a 405 when posting the form, it means the webserver didn't even accept your POST request. So it is not getting as far as executing the PHP code. So none of the suggestions from @Crystal above are useful at all for resolving this specific issue, unfortunately (although the suggestions to turn on mysqli errors are, in more general terms, a good idea).

Comment: The most likely thing which causes this for novice developers is that they try to run their code in a basic webserver (such as the one provided by VS Code) that doesn't support PHP, and doesn't even support all HTTP methods such as POST. You need to either use the [PHP built-in testing server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), or use something like XAMPP or Laragon to install and configure PHP and Apache for you on your machine, so you can test successfully via `http://localhost`, using professional tools.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors from un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values - e.g. a simple `'` in one of your input fields would crash your SQL right now. e.g. what if my surname is `O'Neill`??

Comment: Never configure your web app to login to the database as `root`. Root can do whatever it likes, so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: Please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk (because plain-text passwords can be stolen by hackers). Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords). Hashed passwords cannot be decoded by anyone who steals them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple HTML form, error 405 Method not allowed most likely means that you *don't have PHP installed*, so your server don't know how to handle POST requests.

The simplest way to install PHP on Windows would be

- go to https://windows.php.net/download
- download `.zip` version from the current stable PHP section
- unzip it into a certain folder on your PC (i.e. `C:\PHP`)
- press Win-R, type `cmd.exe` and hit Enter
- switch to the folder of your PHP project, (i.e enter `cd "C:\Users\User\Documents\PHP"` or whatever the folder is and hit Enter)
- enter `C:\PHP\php.exe -S localhost:8080` (using exact folder name where you unzipped PHP)
- then go to your browser and type `http://localhost:8080/script.php`

Or you can use one of prebuilt servers such as XAMPP and such.

On Linux you can install PHP from the packet manager, such as `sudo apt install php`

Comment: That worked to remove the 405 error, but now I get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_report()

Comment: And if I remove that function I get a similar error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: That's great, you have PHP finally working. And now you can google for the next error message, which is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Though the answer would be sudo apt install php-mysql

Comment: Thank you, all the problems are solved, I followed what you said about installing php (I use Arch so the commands and some packages are different) and then I followed what this page says: https://www.webdevsplanet.com/post/call-to-undefined-function-mysqli_connect(). Although I think there is also this solution in StackOverflow.